# can not use store.list soap api method in magento 1.5

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.5

i am not able to list stores using soap method 'store.list'. i am using magento 1.5. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below is my code to retrieve list of stores.

Thanks.

```
$client = new SoapClient('localhost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('user', 'password');
$result = $client->call($session, 'store.list');
print_r ($result);
```

ERROR -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path.
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento15/storeapi.php(11): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
#1 /var/www/magento15/storeapi.php(11): SoapClient->call('a62836877247bba...', 'store.list')
#2 {main}
  thrown in test.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 1):

There was not API available for the `store` in 1.5.
[As you can see here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc)  there is no `api.xml` file in that version.
[Also see here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store) that there is no `Api.php` class for the Store.

They were added in the 1.6 version. See [this](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc) and [this](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store)